# How can I increment the Array

Tags: java

I am not sure if what I am asking is right, but originally i had this run 5 times in the main. however i felt that a do/while loop could do the same thing. But now I cannot get the array shotsMade to change from shotsMade[0] to shotsMade[1] etc, and the shotCount to store to it. It will only store the last run of the while loop. What can I change to make those 2 items increment so the methods still calculate the data correctly

```
import java.util.*;

public class Final {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myGameCounter = 1;  
    int [] shotsMade = new int [5];
    System.out.print("Enter Player's Free Throw Percentage: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int percent = input.nextInt();


    //Game 
do{ 
    System.out.println("Game " + myGameCounter + ":");
    Random r = new Random();
    myGameCounter++;
    int shotCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        boolean in = tryFreeThrow(percent);
        if (in) {
        shotCount++;
        System.out.print("In" + " ");
        }
        else {
        System.out.print("Out" + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Free throws made: " + shotCount + " out of 10");
    System.out.println("");
    shotsMade[0]= shotCount;// I need shotsMade[0] to change each loop, shotsMade[1], shotsMade[2], shotsMade[3], shotsMade[4]
} while (myGameCounter <=5);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Summary:");
    System.out.println("Best game free throws made: " + max(shotsMade));
    System.out.println("Worst game free throws made: " + min(shotsMade));
    System.out.println("Total Free Throws Made: " + sum(shotsMade) + " " + "out of 50");
    System.out.println("Average Free Throw Percentage: " + average(shotsMade) +"%");    


  }      
    public static boolean tryFreeThrow(int percent) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int number = r.nextInt(100);
    if (number > percent){ 
         return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
    public static int average (int nums[]) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        total = total + nums[i];
    }
    int average =  total*10 / nums.length;
    return average;
    }
    public static int sum(int nums[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<nums.length; ++i) {
        sum += nums[i];
    }
    return (int)sum;
    }
    public static int max(int nums[]) {
    int max = nums[0];
    for (int i=1; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] > max) 
            max = nums[i];
    }
    return max;
    }
    public static int min(int nums[]) {
    int min = nums[0];
    for (int i=1; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] < min) 
            min = nums[i];
    }
    return min;
    }

}
```

Comment: `shotsMade[0]= shotCount;`

Comment: Change `shotsMade[0] = shotCount;` to use a variable instead of 0.

Comment: That's unclear. Maybe `shotsMade[myGameCounter - 1]= shotCount;`?

Comment: @RC that seems to cause and exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at Final.main<Final.java:31>....Which is where that code change is.

Comment: myGameCounter starts from 1, you need to start it from 0

Comment: @azurefrog how can i put a variable in the shotsMade[]? it is looking for an index to store the shotCount to. I have tried to think of a way to increment that but i get an exception variable error.

Comment: @RC even changing that still yields same error. It appears its because  the text in there exceeds the scope of the array which is [5]. I could be wrong I am fairly new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Move `myGameCounter++;` just below where you set `shotsMade[]`

   Otherwise, you are increasing the game counter to 2 before the first game finished.
   It should look like:

   `shotsMade[myGameCounter-1]= shotCount;
    myGameCounter++;
   } while (myGameCounter <=5);`
2. Set `shotsMade[myGameCounter-1]= shotCount;` instead of `shotsMade[0]= shotCount;`

   Otherwise, you are overwriting the value of `shotsMade[0]`

This way, you are re-using a counter as index for the array. Since `myGameCounter` will increase by one after each game (after you changed point 1) and it starts from 1, using `myGameCounter - 1` will yield the correct index for your array `shotsMade`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that worked. Didnt realize it was changing the game count before it could store the value.